# How to decide if solution exists for a linear equation?

Tags: linear-algebra, linear-programming

I have $p$ ( $P_1,P_2...P_p$ ) positions and $n$ ( $N_1,N_2...N_n$ ) options to fill each position. Thus I have $n^p$ $p$ length strings. Each of these strings has a variable corresponding to them $\lambda_k$ ( $1 \le k \le n^p $ ). I have the following constraints on these tuples

> For each position $P_i$ let $S_{ij}$ be the set of all the strings having element $N_j$ at this position $P_i$. Then for all all strings $s \in S_{ij}$ 
>   $\sum \lambda_s = C_{ij}$ where $C_ij$ are given constants. ( thus there are $np$ constraints ).

My question is given all $C_{ij}$ is it always possible to assign values to $\lambda_k$ such that all the constraints are satisfied.

Comment: Did you try to find a matrix describing this linear system? If it has full rank, then the answer is yes.

Comment: @5xum I can see it for small cases by hand but in general can't prove it.

Comment: You did not answer my question.

Comment: Got it I made the matrix as you said and number of equations is less than number of variables. Plus all the rows of my matrix all linearly independent as for any two sets $Sij$ and $Skl$ we can find a string that belongs to exactly one set for $i $ not equal to $k$. Also for $i$ equals $k$ and $j$ not equals $l$ there is no common string between the two sets.